# How to use python to return the result of an arithmetic expressions from json?

Tags: python, json

I just want to write a Python program which can takes arithmetic expressions in JSON format, parses and evaluates the answer.

I'm using VS code to write the Python code and I end up by import the JSON file and don't have a clue how should I start the task.

What I expect is the Python can returns the integer evaluating the encoded expression. Can anyone give me a clue by how to do it?

Comment: You should start by finding the root/first operator you need to process.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate any arbitrary mathematical expression in a similar format? If so, I suggest you google "evaluate reverse polish notation". This is a format for mathematical expressions that is used in some calculators. Your example expression would be written as `5 2 * 8 3 - +`. If you learn how to evaluate expressions like this, it is a short jump to evaluating your expressions in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we can implement a function which returns result after arithmetic operations(plus, minus and times) given in JSON format.

- Type can be anything - int, float, long etc..
- Operations supported are `plus`, `minus` and `times`
- `minus` and `times` should have exactly 2 values otherwise `ValueError` exception is raised
- `minus` will return the absoulte difference between 2 numbers

```py
def operation():
    val = 0
    with open("expression1.json") as complex_data:
        data = complex_data.read()
        z = json.loads(data)

    data = z['root']
    for op in data:
        if op == 'description':
            pass
        elif op == 'plus':
            return sum(element[k] for element in data[op] for k in element)
        elif op == 'minus' or op == 'times':
            if len(data[op]) != 2:
                raise ValueError('2 elements expected if operation is minus or times')
            nums = [element[k] for element in data[op] for k in element]
            if op == 'minus':
                return abs(nums[0] - nums[1])
            else:
                return nums[0]*nums[1]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid operation')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got error in the else: return nums[0] * nums[1] which is said unexpected token else and unexpected indent on return

Comment: Oh I think I get it, cause the space before the else thanks, and I want to know if there I have a root which is the plus then I have two child which one is times with two int and other child is mins with two int? Do I still use same thing to implement?

Comment: Not sure, i exactly understood, can you please sample JSON format?

Comment: I'm updated the question above to should another JSON format example

Comment: You will have to update the above function to iterate over data['root'] and consider all  operations(plus, minus and times) recursively!

Answer (score 0):

If the json format will remain the same:

```
def operation(d):
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        s = 0
        addition = d.get('root').get('plus')

        #implement other operation ... substraction = d.get('root').get('minus')

        for i in addition:
            s+=int(i["int"])
        return s


result = operation(z)
```

Basically you have your dictionary z which looks like this:

```
{'root': {'description': 'This expression evaluates to 18. It shows how plus should take 2 or more arguments', 'plus': [{'int': 4}, {'int': 5}, {'int': 4}, {'int': 5}]}}
```

Then you just have to fiddle with it, to get the desired key or value:

```
z.keys()
#dict_keys(['root'])
 z.values()
#dict_values([{'description': 'This expression evaluates to 18. It shows how plus should take 2 or more arguments', 'plus': [{'int': 4}, {'int': 5}, {'int': 4}, {'int': 5}]}]
```

Strongly recommend to check the documentation for dictionary type, here you can find all the methods and looping techniques : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: How about if I have a root which is the plus then I have two child which one is times with two int and other child is mins with two int? How can I implement it? do I set up the times = d.get('child').get('times')?